# Apache2 mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

How do i rewrite static files request like 
http://example.com/assets/img/logo.png
to
http://assets.example.com/img/logo.png

**main site rewrite  rules**

```
    ServerName    example.com
    ServerAlias   example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public/

   <Directory  /var/www/html/example.com/public/ >
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !assets\.site\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|css|js|tiff|woff|woff2|ogg|mp3)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://assets.example.com$1 [NC,L]
```

sub-domain for assets is working properly

**virtual host config for assets.example.com**

```
    ServerName     assets.example.com
    ServerAlias   assets.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public/assets/

   <Directory  /var/www/html/example.com/public/assets/ >
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
```

http://assets.example.com/img/logo.png gives a 404
but if i create a /var/www/html/example.com/public/assets/assets/ then http://assets.example.com/img/logo.png reutns 200

Comment: I don't believe you can do a cross domain rewrite using `mod_rewrite`. I would suggest looking at [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) instead and doing a `proxy_pass`

Comment: i was able to rewrite all /assets/img/logo.png etc to assets.example.com/assets/img/logo.png . Only issues was the repeated '/assets/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, you just need to change the what you're capturing in the regex used by the `RewriteRule`. Right now `$1` is the value of what's in `(.*)`. You can remove "assets" from that by adding it to the path prior to your capture group.

Change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://assets.example.com$1 [NC,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*) http://assets.example.com/$1 [NC,L]
```